# Is this polynomial irreducible over the rationals?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Prove (or disprove): Define  $T_n(x)$ as the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind with degree $n$. If  $p$ is an odd prime, then $\sqrt{\frac{T_p(x)-1}{x-1}}$ is an irreducible polynomial over the rational numbers.

It seems to work shifting $x$ to $x+1$ and using Eisenstein's criterion, but I have no information about the coefficients in the general case. We can use the Pell equation definition and put the polynomial of the second kind to use or maybe use that $T_n(x)=\cos(n \arccos x)$ and see when it is equal to 1, but I have yet to make any progress.

Comment: If the put $A_p(x)=\sqrt{\frac{T_p(x)-1}{x-1}}$, then $A_p(\cos(\theta))=\frac{\sin(\frac{p\theta}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}$ (because of the identity $\cos(t)-1=-2\sin^2(\frac{t}{2})$). So $A_p$ is "almost" a Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind.